# PNG with alpha casting strange shadows depending on viewing angle (Blender 2.91.0)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a RGBA png and i want to render it infront of a plane, but when i do, it casts weird shadows on the plane, the strange part is that the shadows only exist and change under certain viewing angles. video below for reference
I have tried changing shadow setting but so far i really dont know how to fix this problem
im renering in cycles

[Reference YT Video Here](https://youtu.be/N6RBasizaf8)

Comment: Please do not use videos in the question. Use the direct image adding system. It’s considered online protocol not to follow YouTube links you’re not sure of the destination of.

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Also: From that video I can't tell what the problem is.